# Subplot with pandas graphs

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I need to generate a subplot of a row and two columns to show a box diagram and a histogram of data from a dataframe.
I tried this:

```
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
df.boxplot(column=variable)

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
df.hist(column=variable)
```

But I got this :

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7z6mO.png)

How can I get what I need?

> *df* is a pandas dataframe and *variable* contains the name of the column of interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2,figsize=(10,10))
axes[0].boxplot(df3[column])
axes[1].hist(df3[column])
```

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df3 = pd.read_csv('df3')
%matplotlib inline
df3.head()
```

Data:

```
    a           b           c           d
0   0.336272    0.325011    0.001020    0.401402
1   0.980265    0.831835    0.772288    0.076485
2   0.480387    0.686839    0.000575    0.746758
3   0.502106    0.305142    0.768608    0.654685
4   0.856602    0.171448    0.157971    0.321231
```

**generating the figure as specified:**

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2,figsize=(10,10))
axes[0].boxplot(df3['a'])
axes[1].hist(df3['b'])
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Understand that you have to enter a valid column name. To see the names of the columns, do:**

```
df.columns.values.tolist()
```

**In my case:**

```
 df3.columns.values.tolist()
```

Out:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

Comment: You may be entering the name of your column incorrectly, I can use it perfectly, use: `df.columns.values.tolist()` to display the name of the columns correctly

Comment: I tried the last thing you recommended but it didn't work either. Apparently the problem is the existence of the no_data_value found in the dataframe to indicate the missing data.
I just converted the dataframe to numpy array, I took only the positions without the missing value and it already worked, but using pyplot's boxplot and hist functions and not directly with panda dataframes utilities.

Comment: then it was a dataframe problem ... I'm glad it worked out in the end

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2)
axes[0].boxplot(df[variable])
axes[1].hist(df[variable])
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer.I did it but it doesn't work because the boxplot function from pyplot doesn't recognize the parameter called 'column', this is because I want to plot directly from the pandas dataframe boxplot function. Is it possible to do it as I describe or definitely have to extract the data from the dataframe as an numpy array and then use the plotting functions from pyplot?